# Is it possible to recreate User Gestures in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am developing an app and I have encountered a problem that comes down to this scenario:
Consider a superview with two buttons(button1,button2) and a text view, all as its subviews. When I click on one button, I display the text view. When I tap on anywhere outside the textview, but in the super view, I need to dismiss the text view.

I have added a UITapGestureRecognizer to the super view and it calls a method tap:. In tap:, I get the point of the tap and if it is outside the text view, I dismiss the text view and remove the GestureRecognizer. Now the problem occurs when I tap on button 2. I need to dismiss the text view as well as execute the action for button 2. But it enters tap: and I do not wish to call the button 2's method from there.

What I want to know is if it would be possible to emulate the same tap at the same co ordinates after the gesture recognizer is removed? If not what is the way I proceed to solve this issue?

EDIT
I have tried:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

But it does nt solve my problem

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about is it possible to recreate User Gestures in iPhone or not but there is an easy way around you can use to achieve what you need. There is a method you can use is

```
// called before touchesBegan:withEvent: is called on the gesture recognizer for a new touch. return NO to prevent the gesture recognizer from seeing this touch
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
```

You can return whether the `UIGestureRecognizer` should receive touch or in other words should execute the method bound with gesture recognizer. If you return `NO` it will pass the touch to the subviews.

Do not forget to set `delegate` of the gesture recognizer. and including `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol in `.h` file

You can check if the touch is within the button frame then you can `return NO` else `return YES`
Here are the docs [UIGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) [UIGestureRecognizerDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate)

Comment: great answer! sorry for the late reply, but I temporarily don't have access to test this. But from the looks of it, it doesnt solve my problem completely as I want the button to respond to the gesture recognizer whilst executing the button's method.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way for this. This is work fine for me. Please call your method in "UIcontroleventTouchdown" event.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't wish for the button to respond to that event